# TS: get type of object property by variable

Tags: typescript

I'm new in an existing project, where there's some globals defined that come from the backend. It has a corresponding interface:

```js
interface IGlobals {
    feature_foo: boolean
    feature_bar: boolean
    someOtherProp: string
}

const globals: IGlobals = {
    feature_foo: true,
    feature_bar: false,
    someOtherProp: 'hello'
}
```

Now I want to write a function that checks if a certain feature flag exists on that global object. I did that assuming that any property starting with `feature_` will always be a boolean (which in our case it true):

```js
// This is called as: `const isEnabled = useFeature('foo')`
function useFeature(feature: string): boolean {
  const featureKey = `feature_${feature}`

  if (globals.hasOwnProperty(featureKey)) {
    // global starting with `feature_` is always boolean
    return globals[featureKey as keyof IGlobals] as boolean
  }

  return false
}
```

While this works, it feels like a bit of a hack.
I'm mostly bothered by the `as boolean` statement. Which I used because otherwise TS will rightly complain the value could be a boolean or string, which doesn't match with the return value of the function.

Can it be made better?

I have a feeling this may be done with "lookups", but I don't fully grasp that concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! You can make this fully type-safe and completely ignore the need to even have a `.hasOwnProperty` lookup-

```
function useFeature(feature: 'foo' | 'bar'): boolean {
  const featureKey = `feature_${feature}` as const;

  return globals[featureKey];
}
```

(OR)

```
function useFeature(feature: 'foo' | 'bar'): boolean {
  return globals[`feature_${feature}`];
}
```

That's a template literal type, being used as a key. If you restrict the `feature` parameter to the exact feature names, you have it fully type-safe. However, if you would like to be more lenient on the `feature` argument and do an `if` check within, you should have this helper function for narrowing types-

```
function isValidFeature(x: string): x is 'foo' | 'bar' {
  return x == 'foo' || x == 'bar';
}
```

Remember to update the feature list here when you update them in `IGlobals`!

Then, you can just do-

```
function useFeature(feature: string): boolean {
  return isValidFeature(feature) && globals[`feature_${feature}`];
}
```

No casting needed, all type safe and checked thoroughly.

Edit:-
You know what would be better though? Establishing a connection between `isValidFeature` and `IGlobals` directly so you can update features at one place and have it be reflected at the other place. This is where we get into type level programming-

```
const _featureNames = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
const featureNames: string[] = [..._featureNames];

type FeatureKeys = {
  [featureName in typeof _featureNames[number]]: `feature_${featureName}`;
}[typeof _featureNames[number]]

type Features = {
  [featureKey in FeatureKeys]: boolean;
}

interface IGlobals extends Features {
    someOtherProp: string;
    andAnotherOne: number;
}

declare const globals: IGlobals;

function isValidFeature(x: string): x is typeof _featureNames[number] {
  return featureNames.includes(x);
}
```

Now, you can just update feature names within the `_featureNames` tuple and everything will get auto updated. Neat!

Check it out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+gMwKYEMoFcBOSByKC2SEMAvDANoDkCIIlANDJQEYqaUC6MKxokUAbgCwAKD7QYyNFlwEiALhjRMASzABzclzLkAdPsSoM2PIQgdhI0VACeAByQwAYkZkBpJDeJkA3qJgUUsayhDBqMLYOIAjwQTKmRORg6PjMSJgcHIoABnHYcAAkPnkhSAC+2ZZl5JFI0bGuJnIQSSlpGRyi1vaOLtLY3jB+IgHkJR42YWDOjUgT5orMtAA2qGBVXSJqUOkIKMCOAJIA4ssgrMvESAAeO2AAJsR9wcTDAQEQIIQA8lAAFukAAqYEB2RTKNTqSzvbgPACCYBA-3S3zASEUyVS6Q2VhE9yQwGWbEc4lg6jOFwgihOFJQl0sogQ6DAwCgKnAYQgADU6Sp7s8ZAAKa7gqCqDQASkU105ER69UM-VKLUx7S4bxg2GM0xKCQgujUhPQ+IgwolOMZzNZ7Om6AgSAF2EFJVF4vUUpgSxAqxQ0w1Wqw0xU3N5-NmztmEpgADJozByec6S1crNCsVZhULKIyqIgA).

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I should have mentioned that I did not want to re-write the feature names. That looks awesome!  
I'm a bit confused about the `FeatureKeys` type declaration. Is the array at the end used to "fill" the entries inside? Can you explain this? Cheers!

Comment: @publicJorn Yeah that's just a bit of type level programming. Basically, it first uses mapping types to create an object where each value is `feature_${featureName}` (for all feature names). So the object would look like - `{ foo: 'feature_foo'; bar: 'feature_bar' }` in this case. Then, we index the object type by its key type. In typescript, that essentially returns the object value type. Since the object values are constant strings - it returns a union of them - `'feature_foo' | 'feature_bar'`, in this case. Notice how `{ [k: string]: number | boolean }[string]` gives you `number | boolean`.

Comment: I had to read that several times, but I get it now :) Thanks!

Comment: still trying to fully grasp this.. @Chase if you'd be so kind :) Would the above be possible when not separately providing the `_featureNames` array? Ideally the typed "short key" used in `useFeature` is local to that function only. A playground link: https://shorturl.at/hmzLM

Comment: @publicJorn What's a short key? `_featureNames` is needed to build up the `IGlobals` interface (which contains the feature names). `featureNames` is just an array version of `_featureNames`, nothing special. It's needed in `isValidFeature` to type-safely verify the validity of a feature name.

Comment: hm, the url shortener doesn't seem to work. Anyway, thanks for you time again @Chase. I do get the principle, but I guess I need some more practise and read about "type level programming" some more. It's still a bit vague to me.

Comment: @publicJorn If you still have trouble, feel free to create a chat room with your doubts - it's easier to discuss that way. [Here's](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/10305477/chase) is my profile.